# How to import iPhone pictures directly to Flickr to save space?

Tags: data-synchronization, photos.app, photos, import, flickr

I don't like to keep pictures on my small Macbook Air SSD nor on my iPhone, so I am wondering is there a way to upload iPhone pictures directly to my Flickr account without having to import them on my hard drive, and by doing so automatically removing the pictures from my phone to save space?
I tried to do it with iPhoto, but it looks like it always has to import those pictures on my hard drive...
Thanks!

Comment: do you have Flicker on your iPhone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Flicker on your iPhone!!

Click the camera button.

This will take you to the camera screen.

To the left of the camera shutter button is a symbol that looks like 4 layered squares, click that.

This opens up your photo albums, depending on how many albums you have, but usually 'camera roll' will be listed at the top, click and open.

Click on the image you want to upload and hit the 'done' button to the top right - you now be sent to the filter page, from here you can add filters or crop. To access the editing click the pencil symbol, when you finished click done and you'll be brought back to the filters page, add filter or not, then click 'next.

Now you should be at the 'Details' page, here you can add title, description, change privacy levels, share to fb, twitter, tumblr, add location data.

If you want to add tags, add to sets or groups you need to click on 'Advanced'.

When you've finished adding at the info you need to click 'upload'. Job done :)